# VoronoiMesh without edges

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

How can I remove the edges of a VoronoiMesh? I would like to display only the closed cells not touching the border of the image.

This is my binarized source image (imgbw):

[image]

I am doing this:

```
comp = SelectComponents[imgbw, "Area", # > 10 &]; 
meanValues = ComponentMeasurements[MaxDetect[DistanceTransform[comp]], 
           "Centroid"];
listData = meanValues /. Rule -> List;
listData = listData[[All, 2]];
vm = VoronoiMesh[listData];
Show[imgbw, HighlightMesh[vm, Style[1, Black]], ImageSize -> 720]
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**

**New Answer**

Using the `RegionBounds` and `IntersectingQ` functions we can easily achieve this. First we collect the `cells` of the Voronoi diagram and compute their region bounds, then comparing with that of the overall Voronoi diagram we can select the interior polygons.

```
(* vm is the Voronoi diagram of your image *)

cells = MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]; (* cells of the Voronoi diagram *)
regb = RegionBounds[vm]; (* region bounds of the Voronoi diagram *)
inout = IntersectingQ[Flatten@regb, Flatten@RegionBounds[#]] & /@ cells;
in = Pick[cells, inout, False]; (* select the inner polygons *)
```

Here is the plot:

```
Graphics[{Blue, EdgeForm[Black], in}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Old Answer**

Here is one approach:

I will use my sample data here, see below for your image data.

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {20, 2}];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We determine the boundary points using `RegionBoundary` and we set the points from the Voronoi diagram that are on the boundar to `{0,0}`. We do this so we can eliminate the `Polygon`s that coincide with the boundary (this is your goal).

```
nobdr = With[{bdr = MeshCoordinates@RegionBoundary@vor, 
              cod = MeshCoordinates[vor]}, 
             If[MemberQ[bdr, #], {0, 0}, #] & /@ cod]
```

We now get the positions of those boundary points

```
ind = Position[nobdr, {0,0}] // Flatten;
```

And delete the polygons as explained above:

```
pol = DeleteCases[MeshCells[vor, 2], 
  Polygon[{___, Alternatives @@ ind, ___}]]
```

Now the images:

```
gr = Graphics[{LightRed, EdgeForm[Black], GraphicsComplex[nobdr, pol]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With the Voronoi diagram

```
Show[vor, gr]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same approach applied to your data gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In the future, you can get the image by copying the URL and doing something like`imgbw = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/yvNQS.png"]`.

Comment: @2012rcampion. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Can you comment on what you are doing with `Sow` with one argument in your If statement? I'm curious because I don't see any corresponding `Reap`.

Comment: @dionys Please ignore the `Sow` that was a left-over from a previous try.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thank's a lot for your help. - perfect!

Comment: @MilenkoRubin-Zuzic. You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 14):

Shorter, though undocumented:

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Black], 
    MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}]}, ImageSize -> 720]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for playing with tricks where others have to do the dirty work. Are there other specifiers like `"Interior"` that one should know about?

Comment: Great. From where did you get this undocumented info?

Comment: @Milenko Let's just say it is a perk of the job.

Comment: @ilian: Ah, now I understand everything ... I clicked at your name - great that you are helping us. I was last week in Frankfurt and met some developers and also Conrad ...It was more than great to listen to their presentations and to talk to them

Comment: I think the `"InteriorFaces"` can work too.You can get it by `vm[pts]["Properties"]`,But I don't know how to do it.